# Ajax GET request returns "parsererror" for XML containing invalid characters in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xml

I have an app that reads XML file and parse it into data structure. The XML are most of the time fine. Sometime though, the XML would have invalid characters, (i.e. non-breaking space) in it. This code works in Chrome and Firefox. However, it keeps returning parsererror in Internet Explorer (tested in IE11). Is there any workaround to this problem?

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url : path,
    dataType: "xml",
    success: parseXml,
    complete: setupAC,
    error: function(err,status,error) {
        alert("Error reading XML File: "+(status));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a succes function that wraps parseXml in a try/catch block, since the error function will only handle errors generated by the request, not the request success handler.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url : path,
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function( xml ) {
        var data = null;
        try {
            data = parseXml( xml );
        }
        catch ( error ) {
            // handle error in some other way if needed.
        }
        setupAC( data );
    },
    error: function(err,status,error) {
        alert("Error reading XML File: "+(status));
    }
});
```

And then just add a guard into `setupAC()` so that it can handle null values.
Or just do the entire error handling inside the succes handler and a different way to let setupAC know it won't be run with valid input.

Comment: It still behave the same